# Simpler Pandas filter, select datetime columns to dict

Tags: pandas

I have an employee **schedule** that I `filter` to get a DF of `name, timein, timeout` similar to this:

```
employees = [('BOB', datetime(2022,12,1,6,0,0), datetime(2022,12,1,14,0,0)),
('BOB', datetime(2022,12,2,6,0,0), datetime(2022,12,2,14,0,0)),
('GILL', datetime(2022,12,1,6,0,0), datetime(2022,12,1,14,0,0)),
('GILL', datetime(2022,12,3,6,0,0), datetime(2022,12,3,14,0,0)),
('TOBY', datetime(2022,12,1,14,0,0), datetime(2022,12,1,20,30,0))]
labels = ['name', 'timein', 'timeout']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(employees, columns=labels)
```

**I need to compare the timedelta between the current `timeout` and the next `timein` value.** My thought is to filter, select and update to a dict:

`{'BOB' : [(datetime(2022,12,1,6,0,0), datetime(2022,12,1,14,0,0)), (datetime(2022,12,2,6,0,0), datetime(2022,12,2,14,0,0)), etc...}`

Then it should be a simple test (for a common error pattern): `dict['BOB'][i+1][0] - dict['BOB'][i][1] <  fixed_duration`

But Pandas goes through some **Numpy wringer and produces gosh knows what:**

```
results = {}
names = df['name'].unique().tolist()
for name in names:
    times = df.loc[df['name'] == 'BOB', ['schedulein', 'scheduleout']].values.tolist()
    results.update({name: times})
    
results

{'BOB': [[1669874400000000000, 1669903200000000000],
  [1669960800000000000, 1669989600000000000]],
 'GILL': [[1669874400000000000, 1669903200000000000],
  [1669960800000000000, 1669989600000000000]],
 'TOBY': [[1669874400000000000, 1669903200000000000],
  [1669960800000000000, 1669989600000000000]]}
```

**Why can't I get Datetime out?**

**Bonus if you know a more Pandas way to, I call it, *"filter, select"*.**

Comment: `df.groupby('name')['timein'].shift(-1) - df['timeout'] < fixed_duration`?

Comment: `.shift(-1)` is not in my example...? The only way I know to compare two rows is using `iterrow()`, where you skip the first row.

Comment: The first comment shows you a faster one-line solution to computing the timedelta of `timeout[i+1]` and `timedelta[i]`. There is no need to iterate over rows as per your suggestion.

Comment: LOL. You mean this [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html). I misread the suggestion, and thought it was something else (another term for work schedules are "shifts").

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want to do:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

employees = [('BOB', datetime(2022,12,1,6,0,0), datetime(2022,12,1,14,0,0)),('BOB', datetime(2022,12,2,6,0,0), datetime(2022,12,2,14,0,0)),('GILL', datetime(2022,12,1,6,0,0), datetime(2022,12,1,14,0,0)),('GILL', datetime(2022,12,3,6,0,0), datetime(2022,12,3,14,0,0)),('TOBY', datetime(2022,12,1,14,0,0), datetime(2022,12,1,20,30,0))]
labels = ['name', 'timein', 'timeout']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(employees, columns=labels)

results = {}
names = df['name'].unique().tolist()
for name in names:
    times = df.loc[df['name'] == name, ['timein', 'timeout']].astype(object).values.tolist()
    results.update({name: times})

print(results)
```

which gives you:

```
{'BOB': [[Timestamp('2022-12-01 06:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-12-01 14:00:00')], [Timestamp('2022-12-02 06:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-12-02 14:00:00')]], 'GILL': [[Timestamp('2022-12-01 06:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-12-01 14:00:00')], [Timestamp('2022-12-03 06:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-12-03 14:00:00')]], 'TOBY': [[Timestamp('2022-12-01 14:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-12-01 20:30:00')]]}
```